# NSMutableDictionary won't be added to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"]) {
        [records addObject:[currentDictionary mutableCopy]];
    NSInteger size = [records count];
    NSLog(@"Current array size %d",size);
        [currentDictionary release];
}
```

The above code won't add the NSMutableDictionary object to the NSMutableArray. The Log displays '0' as the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please alloc the "records" array using the code

```
records = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in ViewDidLoad().

Comment: I guess that's where the issue comes from : the records is nil, you need to do records = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; (but not necessarily in ViewDidLoad)